# Simpler solution for $5^n+7\equiv{0}\pmod{11}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Simpler solution for $5^n+7\equiv{0}\pmod{11}$
I've solved it as follows:
$5^n\equiv{-7}\pmod{11}\equiv{4}\pmod{11}$
$5^3\equiv{4}\pmod{11}\implies\ 5^4\equiv{9}\pmod{11}\implies\ 5^5\equiv{1}\pmod{11}\implies\ 5^8\equiv{4}\pmod{11}$ etc...
And I deduced that the answer is: $\color{Red}{n=5k+3}$.
Although it seems my solution is correct, I think there should be a more standard and straightforward way for this question.Who knows??

Comment: do you know euler's theorem ?

Comment: Unfortunately no

Comment: Let $a,b$ be fixed. Once we have found one solution $n$ of $a^n\equiv b\pmod{p}$, finding all is relatively straightforward. Finding a solution (if there is one) can be computationally difficult for large $p$. For small $p$ trying $n=1,2,3,\dots$ is reasonably efficient.

Comment: @AndréNicolas You mean such equations can be UNSOLVABLE??!!

Comment: Sure. There is no $n$ such that $5^n\equiv -1\pmod{11}$.  And $-1$ is by no means the only one.